# Cannot resume AudioContext in equalizer

Tags: javascript, media-player, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I use Audio API for HTML player. I created a button for play and use `audio.play()` for it. And after that, I want to code an equalizer, but ChromeDevTols give me this message:

> The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.

I create the AudioContext AFTER the function with `audio.play()` and I don's use autoplay in my player. Also, I will resume audio when HTMLMediaElement (audio) played.

Code equalizer:

```
const eqRanges = document.querySelectorAll('.player__eq-input'),
      audioCtx = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext,
      context = new audioCtx();

audio.onplay = (e)=>{context.resume();}
audio.addEventListener('play',() => context.resume());

function createFilter(frequency) {
      const filter = context.createBiquadFilter();

        filter.type = 'peaking';
        filter.frequency.value = frequency;
        filter.Q.value = 1;
        filter.gain.value = 0;

        return filter;
    }

    function createFilters() {
        const frequencies = [32, 64, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 14000];
        let filters;

        filters = frequencies.map(createFilter);

        filters.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
            prev.connect(curr);
            return curr;
        });
        
        return filters;
    }

    function equalize(audio) {
        const source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio),
              filters = createFilters();
      
        audio.onplay = (e)=>{context.resume();}
        audio.addEventListener('play',() => context.resume());

        source.connect(filters[0]);
        filters[filters.length - 1].connect(context.destination);

        eqRanges.forEach((input, i) => {
            input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                filters[i].gain.value = e.target.value;
            });
        });
    };

    equalize(audio);
```

Comment: It's not clear, but are you not getting any audio?  The console log you see is probably when you created the AudioContext.  I find that message super annoying because it is not wrong to create the context.  It is only wrong if you try to resume the context without a user gesture.

Comment: I find the answer. I have an audio element with a stream URL and for audio context, I need to add a crossorigin="anonymous" for eq. Whatever, I have a message in DevTolls, but now the audio is working!

Comment: Fantastic!  Yet another reason why I hate the message about creating the context.  It hides some of the more relevant messages.